# Compiler design- code generation for expressions with multiple operands

Tags: c, compiler-construction, code-generation, cpu-registers

I am in the middle of coding up a compiler for a C like language.

I have gotten past syntax and semantic checking and I am beginning the code generation phase.

The final code that I have to generate has to be in 3 address load/store architecture. I'm allowed to assume an unbounded set of registers and a 32 M memory space for stack and system memory.

Right now, when I start generating the code, I begin by assuming a really large int array `int R[2000000]` to denote the register set. And as and when I encounter a variable declaration (through the parser/semantic analyzer) I allocate a register for that particular variable.

Now in the course of the program when I encounter this variable again, I retrieve it back from that register number. I save the register number of every variable in the symbol table.

My question now is this: Suppose, we have a statement like this -

```
a := b + c + e / f *h;
```

And I have saved a,b,c,e,f,h in R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6 respectively, the final generated code would be (assuming that the next available regs start from R7...)

```
R9 = R5 * R6;
R8 = R4 / R9;
R7 = R3 + R8;
R1 = R2 + R7;
```

What is the approach to "remember" what was the previous register and the operation?

If this is not the correct way of doing it, can anyone please give me some pointers on how to implement it?

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an unbound register set feels like "cheating". In that case, I guess that you could go right ahead and pick the next available register, as you go along.

In a real-world situation, register assignment is typically done using "graph coloring". In the simple case, a graph consists of nodes representing variables (including temporary values) and arcs representing conflicts between variables. The goal is to assign each variable with a color (representing a register number) so that no two conflicting registers have the same color. (Historically, this problem is similar to the problem of drawing a map of the countries in the world, hence the use of the term "color".)

If the algorithm fail to find a suitable coloring, you have to "spill" some variables, e.g. place them on the stack.

Register allocation can be done either before or after code generation, each will give rise to different interesting problems.

Other things that you might need to consider is calling-convention, where the parameters and return values of a function must be placed in specific registers.

Comment: In fact it is ok to assume an infinite number of registers (btw., why numbering them? Naming works better). And in the next pass you can translate this 3-address code into an SSA form, which makes an efficient register allocation much simpler than the classic graph coloring heuristics. This is exactly what LLVM does.

Answer (score 2):

Register binding should be the very final step.

To generate code for your expression above you should start with turning it to a reverse Polish notation, which looks like this:

```
a b c + e f / h * + :=
```

Now to generate the code we go through this and whenever we encounter an operation, we generate code while maintaining a stack of intermediate results. So let's start. Go through it until the first operation:

```
a b c +
```

So we are supposed to add two variables and store the immediate result. In x86 addition can add only between registers or register and memory. So we must load `b` into a register and add `c` to it:

```
MOV R1, [&b]
ADD R1, [&c]
```

At this point we don't know which register to use, so I marked it with R1.
Now our stack is:

```
a R1
```

Continue and add the next few elements until the next operation.

```
a R1 e f /
```

In x86 division is tricky, the dividend is stored in the EDX:EAX 64 bit pair, the quotient will be in EAX. Assuming you are working with signed 32 bit integers, we must load `e` into EAX and sign extend it to EDX, and the perform the division. So this code needs to be generated:

```
MOV EAX, [&e]
CDQ
IDIV [&f]
```

Fortunately both EDX and EAX is free so we can use it. If they were already used, we would need to save their value in another register to free them up, we don't need to do that now.

The result is in EAX. So our stack now:

```
a R1 EAX
```

Keep going:

```
a R1 EAX h *
```

The first operand is a register, so we don't need to load anything, just do the multiplication right away:

```
IMUL EAX, [&h]
```

The result is in EAX so the stack now:

```
a R1 EAX
```

Continue:

```
a R1 EAX +
```

Again a register to register operation, just a single instruction will do it:

```
ADD R1, EAX
```

The result is in R1. The stack now:

```
a R1
```

And finally the assignment:

```
MOV [&a], R1
```

So the almost final code will be:

```
MOV R1, [&b]
ADD R1, [&c]
MOV EAX, [&e]
CDQ
IDIV [&f]
IMUL EAX, [&h]
ADD R1, EAX
MOV [&a], R1
```

Now it's time to substitute R1. Which register can it be?
The main rule is that register lifetimes must not overlap.
The lifetime of a register that start with a first complete overwrite (like MOV) and ends with the last use before the next complete overwrite (if any).

```
MOV R1, [&b]  ; R1 lifetime starts
ADD R1, [&c]
MOV EAX, [&e] ; EAX lifetime starts.
CDQ           ; EDX lifetime starts
IDIV [&f]     ; EDX lifetime ends.
IMUL EAX, [&h]
ADD R1, EAX   ; EAX lifetime ends.
MOV [&a], R1  ; R1 lifetime ends
```

In our case R1's lifetime overlap with EAX and EDX. So we cannot use them for R1, but EBX is unused so we can use it:

```
MOV EBX, [&b]
ADD EBX, [&c]
MOV EAX, [&e] 
CDQ           
IDIV [&f]     
IMUL EAX, [&h] 
ADD EBX, EAX  
MOV [&a], EBX
```

And after this all registers are free.

And this will be code for your expression. It can be seen that each variable is loaded only once. So there is not much benefit to store them in registers in this particular example. But if your function has multiple statements (and of course will do), the most frequently used variables should be loaded into registers if you can still find a free one after the code for the entire function is generated.

The takeaway is that you should have a plan for each possible scenario, here we saw variable to variable scenario, but sometimes you have stamenents like 4*a, where you can load the a, the shift left instead of multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you may simply enumerate operations and use it number as number of register which hold result value.
If you use tree representation, then register numbers on which operation performed is numbers of child nodes.
Also, you can use [stack machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) for intermediate code representation.

Answer (score 0):

Such expression are often represented with a tree. Each node correspond to an operation, and each node contains the index of the register that holds the result.